# How to map a date value to a timestamp range in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, date-range

I am [using an API](https://developer.pagerduty.com/api-reference/reference/REST/openapiv3.json/paths/~1incidents/get) that takes a date range as part of the payload. The range is specified using 2 datetime parameters indicating the beginning and end of the range:

```
| Name  | Type   | Description                                                | Format              | Required    |
|-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------|
| since | string | The start of the date range over which you want to search. | format: "date-time" | optional    |
|       |        |                                                            |                     |             |
| until | string | The end of the date range over which you want to search.   | format: "date-time" | optional    |
```

When calling this API I want to use a fixed subinterval of the week: `since` as Friday at 8PM, and `until` as Monday at 8AM. I'm currently testing it with a specific date range like this:

```
payload = {
   'since': '2020-03-27T20:00-05',
   'until': '2019-03-30T08:00-05'
}
```

In my script, I want to give a single date as the input, and have that date mapped to a payload that specifies the `since` and `until` for the most recent temporal instance of that interval. I am not sure how to do that, can you help?

Comment: Which Friday and which Monday do you want to use? What would you want to happen if you called this API on a Saturday?

Comment: Wouldn't this kind of information be found in the documentation?

Comment: As @AlecBrooks hints at, you will have to specify *specific* dates that you want to pull for, with this setup there is no getting around that. That said, it's possible to (1) generate requests for many such date ranges, and (2) take an arbitrary date and derive the associated date range where it falls.

Comment: @AlecBrooks The code will be run specifically every Monday, so that it only grabs the incidents from the weekend.

Comment: @Z4-tier OK, I guess there's no getting around the specific dates. I'll try working with the possibilities you pointed out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to be able to take any random date and translate that into a date range Fri 8PM to Mon 8AM?

You can do this:

```
import datetime

def make_payload(date_str):
    today = datetime.date.fromisoformat(date_str)
    monday = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(
                str(datetime.date.fromordinal(
                    (today.toordinal() - today.toordinal() % 7) + 1)) + " 08:00")
    friday = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(
                str(datetime.date.fromordinal(
                    (today.toordinal() - today.toordinal() % 7) - 2)) + " 20:00")
    payload = {'since': friday.isoformat(),
               'until': monday.isoformat()}
    return payload

payload = make_payload('2020-04-07')
print(payload['since'], payload['until'])
```

that will output:

> 2020-04-03T20:00:00 2020-04-06T08:00:00

it takes a date in ISO format as input, and adjusts it to the last Friday-Monday calendar period. You can tweak `monday` and `friday` to give different days if that's not quite what you want, but this gives the basic idea.

Comment: Note: this is probably not the absolute most optimal way to calculate this, and it would perhaps be more idiomatic to use `timedelta`'s to avoid the extra bit of converting back and forth to `str`. That said, this is pretty reasonable, it works, and it's not doing anything too unorthodox.

Comment: This works great. You perfectly understood what I was looking for. Sorry if my initial post was vague or confusing, but thanks a lot. This works for me. :)